# List all offered machine types on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

AWS CLI provides command [`describe-instance-types`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-types.html) to list all offered EC2 instance types. It also allows to filter them by different attributes. Is it possible to do something similar with Google Cloud CLI?

I want to list all offered machine types with their attributes. Additionally, I would like to filter them by their attributes (memory size, cpus, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/machine-types/list

```sh
ZONE="us-west1-c" # For example
gcloud compute machine-types list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter=zone=${ZONE}
```

Yields:

```
NAME              ZONE        CPUS  MEMORY_GB  DEPRECATED
c2-standard-16    us-west1-c  16    64.00
c2-standard-30    us-west1-c  30    120.00
c2-standard-4     us-west1-c  4     16.00
c2-standard-60    us-west1-c  60    240.00
c2-standard-8     us-west1-c  8     32.00
```

> **NOTE** `ZONE` is always `us-west1-c`

And:

```sh
gcloud compute machine-types list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter=guestCpus=8
```

Yields:

```
NAME            ZONE                       CPUS  MEMORY_GB  DEPRECATED
c2-standard-8   us-central1-a              8     32.00
e2-highcpu-8    us-central1-a              8     8.00
e2-highmem-8    us-central1-a              8     64.00
e2-standard-8   us-central1-a              8     32.00
n1-highcpu-8    us-central1-a              8     7.20
```

> **NOTE** `CPUS` is always `8`

You can append `--format=json` or `--format=yaml` to any `gcloud` command to have results presented using those formats.

But for more details (and more filtering) you need to `gcloud compute machine-types describe` (rather than `list`):

```sh
TYPE="n1-standard-1"
gcloud compute machine-types describe ${TYPE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${ZONE}
```

Yields:

```
creationTimestamp: '1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-08:00'
description: 1 vCPU, 3.75 GB RAM
guestCpus: 1
id: '3001'
imageSpaceGb: 10
isSharedCpu: false
kind: compute#machineType
maximumPersistentDisks: 128
maximumPersistentDisksSizeGb: '263168'
memoryMb: 3840
name: n1-standard-1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${PROJECT}/zones/${ZONE}/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
zone: us-west1-c
```

Another way to grok Google's services is through [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer)

For example, Compute Engine's API is [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1)

This is useful in this case because it helps you understand the types that are returned by (every Google API method) including [machineTypes.List](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/machineTypes/list).

From this, you can determine what filtering you wish to employ.

APIs Explorer also provides a way to interact with the underlying REST API directly and, it will generate e.g. `curl` commands for you.

So, instead of `gcloud compute machine-types list ...`, you can:

```sh
PROJECT=...
ZONE=...

TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

# Compute Engine machineTypes.List()
URL="https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${PROJECT}/zones/${ZONE}/machineTypes"

curl \
--silent
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--compressed \
"${URL}?filter=guestCpus%3D8"
```